# Point process weakly modulated by an external signal

Tags: stochastic-processes, point-process

I would like to modulate the probability of firing of a point process by an external signal $x_{ext}(t) $, of varying amplitude and a specific frequency range (filtered Gaussian noise). The mean rate $r$ of the point process is determined by another input. I am currently multiplying the probability of firing by the external signal (normalized to have a mean of 1) to generate this modulation:

$$ P_r = r\times\Delta t \times x_{ext}(t) $$

However, when I implement it in this way the effect of $x_{ext}(t) $ on the probability of firing is not constant as $r$ increases.

Is there a better way of  modulating the signal so that the influence of the  $x_{ext}(t) $ is not so dependent on the $r$? I think some variation of a conditional intensity function may work, where the amplitude/frequency of the intensity can be chosen, but I'm not sure how to implement it for this case.

Any advice would be much appreciated.